# Niqqud for שְׁיָרֵי in Zevachim mishnah

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, mishna

I am really no expert in Hebrew grammar and I know there are many variants of same word. In particular I think there is no tradition for the puntuaction of the Mishnah.

However in my siddur (Panzieri, Italian rite) I noticed that  שירי הדם, in the Mishnah of "Eizehu meqoman shel zevachim" is spelled שִׁיְּירֵי, while in all the other siddurim I have seen so far it is שְׁיָרֵי. What puzzles me in the version of the Panzieri is the "sheva + yud" form that I have not thought to be possible. Can I assume that the form Panzieri is incorrect or is it an admissible variant?

In order to prevent rendering issues I write here the two forms in full:
Panzieri = shin with hirik - yud with dagesh and sheva - yud without puntuaction - resh with tzere - yud without puntuaction
Regular = shin with sheva - yud with qamatz - resh with tzere - yud without puntuaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *yod* with a *dagesh* and a *sh'va* after a *chirik* is possible. It appears in [*Ester* 9:27](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%98_%D7%9B%D7%96) (first word). So that answers your question about complete impossibility. That said, I don't know whether it's the correct vowelization of שירי.

As for the *yod* without punctuation after the *sh'va*, such a *yod* is often added in unvoweled text to indicate that the preceding *yod* is voweled (has a *sh'va*, as opposed to being a mater lectionis). I haven't seen it in voweled text<sup>[1]</sup>, but suspect that that's why it's present above; I suspect, too, that it's an error caused by someone's copying the extra *yod* from an unvoweled copy.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>Not necessarily true. *Tanach* has many examples of letters not pronounced at all: these appear unvoweled. One example according to many is the second *sin* in *Yisachar*. It may well be that a *yod* appears sometimes (as in your example of שִׁיְּירֵי) in *Tanach* like that, though I don't know of any. (To be honest, I know very little on the topic of these unpronounced letters.) But this is irrelevant, in that this is a *m'sorah* issue in *Tanach* and shouldn't carry over to words in *Mishna* (that are not copied from *Tanach*).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, still, my problem is the _yod_ without punctuation after the _sheva_

Comment: @Ralph, I've edited the answer to include what little I know about that. I had misunderstood the question as asking about the _yod_ with _sh'va_ rather than as asking about the _sh'va_ after the _yod_.

Answer (score 1):

In the Nussach Ariza"l Siddurim (per Rabbi Shneur Zalman of Liadi, first Chabad Rebbe) it has one Yud and the Nikkud is Shee-ray and so it is in the Pirkei Avos Perek 1 Mishna 2 Shimon Hatzadik Hoyo Mee-shee-ray... (check your Siddur by Pirkei Avos).

Comment: Do you mean that there's a _chirik_ under the _shin_ and nothing under the _yod_ immediately following? If so, that's odd, as that word means "songs of" (as in "_habocher b'shire zimra_").

Comment: There is nothing under the Yud, but like in other languages Hebrew also has words that have more than one meaning to them. (In a similar vein the word Mimenu could mean 'from us' or 'from him'.)

Comment: This is the same in the Machzor Polin MiKol HaShonoh.

Answer (score 1):

Codex Kauffman A50, [widely considered](https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/The_Literature_of_the_Jewish_People_in_t/A-d5DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA253&printsec=frontcover) to be the best representative of the Western-type Mishnah, has שִׁירֵי.

[image: MS Kauffman]

Answer (score 0):

R' Yaakov Emden has it [in his siddur](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=19725#p=156&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) as שִׁיְרֵי (so nearly the same as in your siddur, but without the second yud and without the dagesh in the first one). In his commentary further down the page he notes that this is the more typical usage in Chazalic literature, but that שִׁיּוּרֵי would be an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Azor Eliyahu siddur, the old Askinazi sidurrim mostly have she-rai (chirik on the shin and no vowelizaion on the yud), the [Siddur Rashash](https://jewiki.org.il/w/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.95) (from the time of the Maharsha and Bach) has sheyirai (like in the OP, without the double yud), and the [Vayiater Yitzchok](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91) changed the vowelization to shiyarei (with a kamatz). So there is no reason to assume the Panzieri siddur has a mistake.